# Prevent imagemagick from mogrifing an image twice

Tags: debian, imagemagick, mogrify

So i have a folder that has a lot of images. I use imagemagick to optimize all the images inside the folder. I aborted the command to "optimize" the images. Now. Some images have been optimized but not all. So I must run the command again. Is there a way that imagemagick skip the images that have already been optimized?

This is what i usually do to optimze all the images:

```
for i in *.jpg; do mogrify -quality 85 "$i"; done
```

Comment: I do not know of any way for ImageMagick to know that you already processed a file. But your command is not very efficient. You are using mogrify to process one file and then looping over all files. The purpose of mogrify is to process a whole folder of files by itself. So either use convert in place of mogrify in  the loop. Or just use mogrify to process all the files in the folder in one command with no loop. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Comment: When I don't use the loop command I get: argument list too long in debian. Do you have a suggestion on how to do it any other way? cause 60k images is too much (even when you use a simple command like mv or rm)

Comment: Then I suggest that you simply replace mogrify with convert and keep your loop. It won't change much for you, but convert is more flexible. So if you have more complex commands, it will work, but mogrify might not. Use syntax `convert input -quality 85 output` where output can be the same as input. Or just keep your mogrify as it is for simple commands. I suggest you time both and see which is more efficient.

Comment: One other thought. You could just check the quality of the image before processing. If 85 or less, do not process it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tens of thousands of images to process, and a decent fairly modern machine (i.e. multi-core CPU and decent RAM and disks), you could consider **GNU Parallel**.

Basically, you need to pipe the filenames into **GNU Parallel** if there are more than your system's ARGMAX limit. It is best to use null-terminated names so that filenames including spaces continue to work, so you'd want:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | parallel -0 --dry-run mogrify -quality 85 {}
```

If that looks correct, you can remove the `--dry-run` and run it again for real. As it is, that will keep 4 copies of `mogrify` running in parallel if your CPU has 4 cores - i.e. it will keep them all busy and should process your images miles faster, However, it is not most efficient because it starts a whole new `mogrify` process for every image, it is better to add `-X` to **GNU Parallel** and then it will start `mogrify` with as many filenames as your OS can handle and the cost of starting the one process will be amortised over a large number of images. That would be:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | parallel -0 -X mogrify -quality 85 {}
```

---

Make your experiences with any new software on a **copy** of your data - **GNU Parallel** can do lots of stuff very fast - good stuff and bad!